# Toolbar button stays in-active in Cocoa Xcode 6 Storyboard Mac App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am trying to add a simple IBAction to the Toolbar in the storyboard. I simply added the object to Window in the Window Controller and dragged at Image Toolbar Item to it. Added an image to it and placed in by default. Next I added a new class and called it ToolbarButtons and added an object to the Window Controller with this class. Finally I dragged the Image Toolbar Item I added to them ToolbarButtons.h file to create an IBAction. In the function I simply wrote to NSLog.

The button stays grey even though a function is assigned to it. The weird thing is that everything works if instead of using my own class I use AppDelegate.

Any ideas why? I am using Xcode 6.3 if this is important.

Thanks

Comment: You need to read about the responder chain and NSUserInterfaceValidation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am fairly new to objective-c so I think I have to read a lot before I really understand how to use your suggestion. Thanks for showing me the right direction. however, if you could elaborate a little bit more it would be nice.

Comment: So I extended the class ->  @interface ToolbarButtons : NSObject <NSUserInterfaceValidations> and I added - (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)item; in header and in the function I added: - (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)item {
    
    if ([item action] == @selector(toolbarButton1:)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
And I also have - (IBAction)toolbarButton1:(id)sender { ...} connected to the toolbar item. but still not working. the same method in AppDelegate works.